# How can I re-open my question?

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question

A couple of days ago I asked [How likely is it for coastal cities to survive next 40 years?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/21318/6031). It was proposed in comments to make it more narrow, as it's hard to predict all possible scenarios around the globe. I edited my question but later the same day it was closed as opinion based.

I believe with the changes in the question it fulfills required criteria but as I already made my changes I don't have an idea what to do next to make it open again

Comment: The last version available has many questions included, of which several are not Earth Science in nature.  You need to limit the post to one question that is Earth Science focused.

Comment: I think you can do some more edits and that may trigger re-open voting. The title is still "How likely is it for coastal cities to survive next 40 years?" and that needs to be updated to match the body of your question. Also, instead of a separate "Edit" section at the end (where many readers will never see it having made up their mind already that the question is too broad or likely to have answers that are opinion-based) just **edit your question** itself. Clean up loose ends, keep every sentence focused on one single question, and fix that title!

Comment: Also, make sure that the title and body of the question asks for fact-based answers. Instead of "Do you think that St. Petersburg will be under water in 40 years?" ask something like "Are there models that address... St. Petersburg...?" That way answers can point to models rather than propose their own.